# Cocos2d Spritesheet. Is it true that using Spritesheets I cannot set the Z-order of the sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I read on some forums that using Spritesheets in Cocos2d I cannot set the Z-order of the sprites belonging to the same Spritesheet. Is it true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is incorrect and inaccurate. A spritesheet is a texture atlas, you can do anything with sprites created from a texture atlas.

If you use a CCSpriteBatchNode you can use zOrder for all the sprites added to the same node, but multiple batch nodes and their respective children sprites are sorted based on the batch node order and their zOrder. So if batchnode A is drawn behind batchnode B then none of B's children can be zOrder sorted to be behind any of batchnode A's sprites.

However even then you can still freely z-order batched sprites with multiple batch nodes by enabling depth buffering and using the vertexZ property, which is the "true" OpenGL depth value. It's a bit slower and consumes more memory though.